# Jackson.Json. что делать, когда строка названа числовым значением

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Есть следующий Json

```
 "car": {
                "0": "bentley cont",
                "1": "2.5",
                "2": "2015"
            }
```

Как правильно ее обьявить в Jackson, чтобы начать с ней работать.

```
public class PjCartItemStringCar {
private String 0,1,2???;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было дописать @JsonProperty

```
@JsonProperty("0")
private String _0;
@JsonProperty("1")
private String _1;
@JsonProperty("2")
private String _2;
```

Comment: Совет: называйте все переменные так, чтобы было понятно для чего они, а для Jackson навешивайте аннотацию